# How to loading tiles.xml from src/main/resources

Tags: spring, tiles

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hn05.png)

i want to use tiles.xml from  src/main/resources using classpath:/ but i dont know how classpath find tiles.xml or how to config path for classpath. it seem only fine in webapp. help me. thanks

Comment: Refer: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Comment: no i want using same this: "classpath:/abc/tiles.xml"

Comment: Try classpath:abc/tiles.xml

Comment: it is not working